# Mysql left join issue with 3 tables not returning all rows from first table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have below query

```
select  catid, cat_name, currency, count(is_reporting_category_sales.id) as total_sales, 
sum(total_sales) as total_earning 
from is_category 
  left join is_reporting_category_sales on is_category.catid = is_reporting_category_sales.category_id 
  join is_reporting_order on is_reporting_order.id = is_reporting_category_sales.order_id 
group by catid, cat_name, currency 
ORDER BY `is_category`.`cat_name` ASC
```

but this is returning only rows that are common in is_category and `is_reporting_category_sales`, `is_reporting_order` but I want to fetch all rows from `is_category table`. And if there is no order for the category then `0` as `total_earning` and `total_sales`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to Use Left Join

```
left join is_reporting_order on is_reporting_order.id = is_reporting_category_sales.order_id
```

Instead of

```
join is_reporting_order on is_reporting_order.id = is_reporting_category_sales.order_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps using left outer joins you might get the results you expect ( had to guess at some of the aliases for columns btw so some of them might be wrong )

```
select  c.`catid`, c.`cat_name`, `currency`, count(i.`id`) as 'total_sales', sum(`total_sales`) as 'total_earning' 
from `is_category` c
  left outer join `is_reporting_category_sales` i on c.`catid` = i.`category_id`
  left outer join `is_reporting_order` on o.`id` = i.`order_id`
group by c.`catid`, c.`cat_name`, `currency`
order by c.`cat_name` asc;
```